# How to open camera in google chrome without asking permission using python

Tags: python

I could able to run my code and open camera in internet explorer and also in firefox but the code could not able to open in google chrome using my IP address

here is my py:

```
from flask import Flask,render_template

app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return render_template('main.html')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='192.168.1.80')
```

main.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Face_Reg</title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css.css')}}">
</head>
<body>
<h3>SHOW YOUR FACE</h3>

<div class="container">

  <div class="app">

    <a href="#" id="start-camera"  class="visible">Touch here to start the app.</a>
    <video id="camera-stream"></video>
    <img id="snap">

    <p id="error-message"></p>

    <div class="controls">
      <a href="#" id="delete-photo" title="Delete Photo" class="disabled"><i class="material-icons">delete</i></a>
      <a href="#" id="take-photo" title="Take Photo"><i class="material-icons">camera_alt</i></a>
      <a href="#" id="download-photo" download="selfie.png" title="Save Photo" class="disabled"><i class="material-icons">file_download</i></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Hidden canvas element. Used for taking snapshot of video. -->
    <canvas></canvas>

  </div>

</div>


<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js.js')}}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is my js:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    // References to all the element we will need.
    var video = document.querySelector('#camera-stream'),
        image = document.querySelector('#snap'),
        start_camera = document.querySelector('#start-camera'),
        controls = document.querySelector('.controls'),
        take_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#take-photo'),
        delete_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#delete-photo'),
        download_photo_btn = document.querySelector('#download-photo'),
        error_message = document.querySelector('#error-message');


    // The getUserMedia interface is used for handling camera input.
    // Some browsers need a prefix so here we're covering all the options
    navigator.getMedia = ( navigator.getUserMedia ||
    navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
    navigator.msGetUserMedia);


    if(!navigator.getMedia){
        displayErrorMessage("Your browser doesn't have support for the navigator.getUserMedia interface.");
    }
    else{

        // Request the camera.
        navigator.getMedia(
            {
                video: true
            },
            // Success Callback
            function(stream){

                // Create an object URL for the video stream and
                // set it as src of our HTLM video element.
                video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

                // Play the video element to start the stream.
                video.play();
                video.onplay = function() {
                    showVideo();
                };

            },
            // Error Callback
            function(err){
                displayErrorMessage("There was an error with accessing the camera stream: " + err.name, err);
            }
        );

    }



    // Mobile browsers cannot play video without user input,
    // so here we're using a button to start it manually.
    start_camera.addEventListener("click", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        // Start video playback manually.
        video.play();
        showVideo();

    });


    take_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        var snap = takeSnapshot();

        // Show image.
        image.setAttribute('src', snap);
        image.classList.add("visible");

        // Enable delete and save buttons
        delete_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");
        download_photo_btn.classList.remove("disabled");

        // Set the href attribute of the download button to the snap url.
        download_photo_btn.href = snap;

        // Pause video playback of stream.
        video.pause();

    });


    delete_photo_btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){

        e.preventDefault();

        // Hide image.
        image.setAttribute('src', "");
        image.classList.remove("visible");

        // Disable delete and save buttons
        delete_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");
        download_photo_btn.classList.add("disabled");

        // Resume playback of stream.
        video.play();

    });



    function showVideo(){
        // Display the video stream and the controls.

        hideUI();
        video.classList.add("visible");
        controls.classList.add("visible");
    }


    function takeSnapshot(){
        // Here we're using a trick that involves a hidden canvas element.

        var hidden_canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'),
            context = hidden_canvas.getContext('2d');

        var width = video.videoWidth,
            height = video.videoHeight;

        if (width && height) {

            // Setup a canvas with the same dimensions as the video.
            hidden_canvas.width = width;
            hidden_canvas.height = height;

            // Make a copy of the current frame in the video on the canvas.
            context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

            // Turn the canvas image into a dataURL that can be used as a src for our photo.
            return hidden_canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
        }
    }


    function displayErrorMessage(error_msg, error){
        error = error || "";
        if(error){
            console.error(error);
        }

        error_message.innerText = error_msg;

        hideUI();
        error_message.classList.add("visible");
    }


    function hideUI(){
        // Helper function for clearing the app UI.

        controls.classList.remove("visible");
        start_camera.classList.remove("visible");
        video.classList.remove("visible");
        snap.classList.remove("visible");
        error_message.classList.remove("visible");
    }

});
```

My java-script consist of three icon  'camera' which is used for take pictures and 'Delete' icon for deleted picture and 'download' icon for downloading captured images but this showing me more attractive camera but i does not opening in google chrome.
How can i rectify it can anyone help me..Please

screenshot of my output in google chrome

[image]

Comment: You need to check 2 Permissions. Chrome need the permission and your script. Is your camera enabled in chrome?

Comment: Chrome just allowed https:// to do this without asking. you need to set your webserver to https. [Here maybe usefull informations for https](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,32986) and if you call local file instead your URL it should work, too.

Comment: Sir., thank you i m trying this but if i run using https:// i'm getting Error like "This site can’t provide a secure connection"

Comment: Is your web-server configured for https-usage? Maybe ssl handshake not working - does it look like [this](https://www.conetix.com.au/support/article/ssl-error-site-cant-provide-secure-connection)? you need to create own certificat which should bring this to work but viewed as "not secured" because it´s not registered - just have a try

Comment: sir., how can i create own certificate for this chrome.

Comment: you need to create it locally and store it on your webserver which provides the called page. You can use OpenSLL with windows to create it. there are many how-to´s which will help you creating the page with https/ssl  - good luck

Comment: And don´t forget to open the connection the right way with https and not http:// - this should be enable, too. Websites can use both if you not force it this way. and then http:// doen´t found the page.